# How can I set text wrapping on an Excel chart in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, microsoft-office-2007, word-wrap

I'd like to apply square text wrapping to an Excel chart inserted into my document. The normal options don't seem to exist. Is there any way of doing this other than inserting the chart into a textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found it. Not on the right click menu, but in the format tab. Why can't Word be consistent?